# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass while inserting data in mongo using Spring MongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I am trying to insert some data (List of Objects) into mongoDB using Spring MongoTemplate and I am getting an exception:

```
14:08:04.430 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator - Analyzing class class Child1 for index information.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory$PropertyAccessorClassGenerator.generateCustomAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.createAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.potentiallyCreateAndRegisterPersistentPropertyAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.getPropertyAccessor(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:455)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations$AdaptibleMappedEntity.of(EntityOperations.java:592)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations$AdaptibleMappedEntity.access$100(EntityOperations.java:570)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.EntityOperations.forEntity(EntityOperations.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsertBatch(MongoTemplate.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1268)
```

Data is actually an Object which is created using builder pattern something like:

```java
abstract public class Parent <? extends Parent<?>> {
      private String parentId;
      public String getParentId(){
        return parentId;
      }
      public B setParentId(String parentId){
        this.parentId=parentId;
      }
      abstract B self() {};
}
```

Child class:

```java
public class Child1 extends Parent<Child1> {
      private String childId;
      public String getChildId(){
        return childId;
      }
      public Child1 setChildId(String childId){
        this.childId=childId;
      }
      public Child1 self() {
        return this;
      };
}
```

Second Child class:

```java
public class Child2 extends Parent<Child2> {
    private String childId;
    private String childValue;

    public String getChildId(){
        return childId;
    }

    public Child2 setChildId(String childId){
        this.childId=childId;
    }

    public String getChildValue(){
        return childValue;
    }

    public Child2 setChildValue(String childValue){
        this.childValue=childValue;
    }

    public Child2 self() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

MongoUtil and Main class:

```java
public class MongoUtil {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public static void persistToMongo(List<? extends Parent<?>> listOfObjects, String collectionName) {

        //Here the exception is thrown.
        mongoTemplate.insert(listOfObjects, collectionName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child1 child1 = new Child1().setChildId("id1").setParentId("parentId1");
        List<Child1> child1List = new ArrayList<>();
        child1List.add(child1);

        MongoUtil.persistToMongo(child1List, "someCollection");

        Child2 child2 = new Child2().setChildId("id2").setParentId("parentId2").setChildValue("val2");
        List<Child1> child2List = new ArrayList<>();
        child2List.add(child1);

        MongoUtil.persistToMongo(child2List, "someCollection");

    }
}
```

If I try with normal extends class without any Generics, it works fine but then I will have to trade off with builder pattern and in my class I have way too many members and builder pattern makes using them easily.
Moreover, I don't want to create separate methods of `persistToMongo` to take `List<Child1>` and `List<Child2>` separately.

Any help will be appreciated!.

Thanks,
Ashit

Comment: Hi, There was some dependency conflict problem because of which it was not happening. After resolving that, I am able to insert the documents now.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem and removed the spring-core dependency.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

There was some dependency conflict problem because of which it was not happening. After resolving that, I am able to insert the documents now.

Comment: Please specify which dependency conflict